Colored glass casting colored shadow on smoke
I use the "Glass BSDF" material, with "Beckman" algorithm, IOR 1.450 to get colored shadows through glass: . Blender Version is 4.2.1 LTS.
I then added a quick smoke effect (in white color), which should receive the colored shadows and be colored in the shadow color. But it doesn't receive the color, it stays in shades of gray: .
The renderer I use is Cycles, from what I've read it's the best for colored glass and colored shadows.
I found lots of tutorials on how to change the smoke color in general. I don't want to know that, the smoke should be white in general, but it should get its light-coloring mostly from the colored shadows.
Is there some shader (and/or settings) I should add to the Smoke Domain?
Edit: I changed the light color to green and set it to a really high value, it colors the white smoke like it should, but the colors coming from the glass don't affect the smoke, you see only parts of the floor shimmering through, which is correctly colored (as you can see in the very 1st picture): .

What are your render settings?

@TheLabCat The list of possible render settings is enormous. I would say: Nothing special. Can you be more specific at which settings I should look?

I solved it, @TheLabCat was right, my render settings were missing something, and ChatGPT pointed me in the right direction, what settings exactly were wrong.
I had to go to Light Paths > Max Bounces > Volume which was set to 0. I increased it to 8, setting it higher didn't seem to change anything visibly. But the result was still not satisfying, it seemed like only a few particles were illuminated, like 25%, which looked wrong. So out of an assumption I increased the Sampling > Render > Samples from 128 to 256, which did it.
Settings:
.
The result was finally satisfying:

I'm still not 100% satisfied, since the smoke coloring is still far to dim, compared to the glass, which is overexposed, but I think I can tweak that.

Ok, dunno why you had those turned down to begin with, but maybe it was the guy before you. Anyways, ye: 128 is a bare minimum sample count when volumetrics aren’t involved, and if light can only bounce once, well, things gonna look dark.
